# Phabricator Markdown header bug?

Tags: markdown, phabricator

This is the code for the markdown section:

```
## Authors/Leaders

 * Scarecröwman (classified): Fearless Leader
 * TMcSquared(Thomas/Tre'): Lead Code Wrangler/Design
 * NewbProgrammer101(Jay): Repository Sentry
 * toby109tt (Toby): Lead Graphics Tamer
 * ...and more!

## Dependencies

 * [Cinder](https://www.libcinder.org/)
 * [cpgf](http://www.cpgf.org/)
 * [PawLIB](https://mousepawmedia.com/projects/libraries/pawlib)
 * [Lua/LuaJIT](https://www.lua.org/)
 * [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/)
```

however, this is what it looks like on Phabricator:
[image: screenshot]

It renders properly on GitHub though.
Can anyone tell me why this would happen or if you've come across something like this, thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place for questions, not for bug reports.

Comment: oops, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

I guess it happens because a single leading # is also used for numeric lists, and the header is followed by a list, so some code in the list handling is pulling it into the list as the first item.

It looks like a bug in the Remarkup parser, and I suggest reporting it here: 
https://discourse.phabricator-community.org/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the `##` made Phab think that the list was numbered.
Adding plain-text inbetween the `##` and the first `-` fixes the problem.

Comment: Or you can use another header syntax to avoid the problem if you don't want plain text in between. Both GitHub and Phabricator support the ==== underline style (though it isn't well documented on GitHub).